# creating pdf through pdfbox using inputstream

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

i am trying to add byte array to pdfbox box but unable to achieve it.. please find below the code

```
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    
    import org.apache.pdfbox.Loader;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts;
    
    public class App 
    {
    
    public static String getPDF(Blob l_bContent) throws IOException {
    
    InputStream stream = l_bContent.getBinaryStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bytesRead;//enter code here
        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byte[] buffer1= baos.toByteArray();
        PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(buffer1);
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        
        doc.addPage(page);
        
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\dhs\\new.pdf";
        doc.save(fileName);    
    
       stream.close();    
        
         return fileName;
        
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       Blob l_bContent =managerservice.getblobcontent();
        App test1 = new App();
        try {
            test1.getPDF(l_bContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

**error**

> java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line at offset 5
> Hello World!
> at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1092)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:1609)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:1588)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:157)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:136)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:224)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:196)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:176)
> at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadPDF(Loader.java:159)
> at pdftest.testpdf.App.getPDF(App.java:36)
> at pdftest.testpdf.App.main(App.java:85)

Comment: You just deleted the same question and put it back with the same wrong code, treating text as pdf data - why??

Comment: So the blob contains a PDF file?

Comment: yes it is  the blob contains it :(

Comment: The exception suggests that the blob is a text file that starts with "Hello"

Comment: Why not `PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(l_bContent.getBinaryStream());` in that case?

Comment: PDDocument.load is not working with 3 version of pdfbox .. Loader.load is working .. let me check with that

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows ... Loader.LoadPDF is also giving error .. The method loadPDF(byte[]) in the type Loader is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream)

Comment: You've probably got either a text file or a corrupt PDF. Save it and try to open it `Files.copy(l_bContent.getBinaryStream(), Path.of("questionable.pdf"));`

Comment: Your `System.out.println("it came back "+baos);` clearly shows what's in the buffer. Just plain text, no PDF.

Comment: buffer1 contains this data while debugging [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]

Comment: *...clearly shows what's in the buffer* No, that won't as baos has no meaningful `toString`

Comment: Bios has a string "Hello" only which i saw in debugging.. the pdf conatains the word Hello

Comment: *buffer1 contains this data while debugging* Irrespective of what that is, how *could* it be a valid pdf?

Comment: *Bios has a string "Hello" only* - so as has been said all along, you need to turn a text file into a pdf file

Comment: Let me try to run again with text ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is almost certainly down to the fact that your source data is almost certainly plain text, try the following [(with thanks)](https://github.com/anitalakhadze/apache-pdfbox-demo):

```
    public static void saveAsPdf(InputStream in, String outputPath) {
        try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage pdPage = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(pdPage);

            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdPage);
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(in)) {
                contentStream.beginText();

                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
                contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 500);

                while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                    contentStream.showText(s.nextLine());
                    contentStream.newLine();
                }

                contentStream.endText();
            }

            doc.save(outputPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
```

Comment: not every argument is worthless... thanks for this solution... It's working for me.. Grateful for the guidance. :)